# (How) Can I get GUID from an IWbemClassObject object?

Tags: c++, guid

I want get updates from a server for certain apps and I need to know their GUID. I started from a piece of code I found [here](http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2011/05/01/finding-installed-applications-with-vc/), but I can't figure out how to get the GUID in

`tstring WmiQueryValue(IWbemClassObject* pclsObj, LPCWSTR szName)`

for `pclsObj`. I tried passing both `"GUID"` and `"Guid"` in `szName`, but I don't get anything.

Is there anyway to get the GUID this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pclsObj` is a `Win32_Product`, you find that out with szName "__CLASS" for `WMIQueryValue`. I looked it up and this class has `IdentifyingNumber` as member, which stores the GUID :)